# I need to convert a returned number in a report with text?

Tags: text, crystal-reports, numbers

I have a value in a report that is returned as a number for example 1 - What i am trying to do is whenever 1 is displayed in the report i want it to show text such as Program Live.

I am using crystal 9, any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Create a crystal formula and use this code:

```
if {numeric var} = 1 then
    "Program Live"
else
    ""
```

You can then place the formula on your report.  Hope this helps.
Wade